# jQuery/Mapbox multiple data filters issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, mapbox

I have a map, built in Mapbox, that feeds off of a GeoJSON. I'm trying to filter markers by two criteria: category (multiple true/false properties) and year. I want the two filters to work at the same time, not cancel each other out, but I'm getting stuck when combining them.

Each filter works independently — this is what I have for year:

```
$('.year a').on("click", function() {
    var year = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    featureLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
        return (year === 'all' || f.properties.Year === year);
    });
    return false;
});
```

and this is what I have for category:

```
$('.category a').on("click", function() {
    var category = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    featureLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
        return ((category === 'all') ? true : f.properties[category] === true);
    });
    return false;
});
```

This is how I combined them, but I know I'm doing something wrong.

```
$('.category a, .year a').on("click", function() {
    var category = $(this).data('filter');
    var year = $(this).data('filter');
    $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
    featureLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
        return ((category === 'all') ? true : f.properties[category] === true) &&
        (year === 'all' || f.properties.Year === year);
    });
    return false;
});
```

I think I'm missing a step to differentiate the two filter searches, but I'm not very familiar with jQuery, so I'm not sure what I need to do. Specifically, I think I'm missing the part where the category var gets associated with .category a, and year var gets associated with .year a.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: your category and year are getting set to the same thing!

Comment: Do you have a live example sitting around somewhere? @MattParrilla is  right but it's tough to confirm if that's the problem.

Comment: @BillMorris Yes! It's here: http://www.sevendaysvt.com/general/multimedia/projects/stuckinvtmap/stuckmap5.html

Comment: hmm, that return also isn't working as you expect

Answer (score 2):

suoz,

Your problem might be the way you are targeting the selectors to bind the click event. The right way is:

```
$('.category a, .year a').on('click', function() { ... });
```

You don't said the issue, but I think this might be the problem or one of them.

Comment: Thanks, Inacio - you're right, I didn't feed in the selectors right.

I've corrected this and the "select all" features for both filters are now working, but it's still not filtering by category or year, so I think my code has other problems as well. Am I missing something else?

Comment: @suoz, your code is not wrong, besides the selector issue. I think you are doing the wrong thing, though.
You should try this approach from the Mapbox examples: https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/filtering-marker-clusters/

Answer (score 1):

You're currently setting `year` and `calendar` to the same value. Try directly targeting the elements instead of using `this` to avoid that problem.

```
$('.category a, .year a').on("click", function() {

  var category = $('.category a').data('filter');
  var year = $('.year a').data('filter');

  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  featureLayer.setFilter(function(f) {
      return ((category === 'all') ? true : f.properties[category] === true) &&
      (year === 'all' || f.properties.Year === year);
  });
  return false;
});
```